# UIPickerview not calling titleForRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a single uipickerview and I am trying to populate it with a list of dr's from a coredata database.  I am loading the list of dr's in viewdidload and have verified they are there with nslog statments.  After verifying they are there, I do a reloadallcomponents and my pickerview shows an appropriate number of "?" marks.  When I put in breakpoints, I notice that my app goes through and gets the number of rows twice, and returns the appropriate number, but the titleforrow method is never getting called.  Any thoughts?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"there are %d doctors",[self.doctors count]);
    return [self.doctors count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"Row %d has dr %@",row,[self.doctors objectAtIndex:row]);
    return [self.doctors objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the picker view's `delegate` in addition to its `dataSource`?

Comment: Are `titleForRow:` and `numberOfRowsInComponent:`/`numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` not all datasource methods?

Comment: @nhgrif Are you asking me? Looks the docs.

Comment: Hmm, looks like not.  The two `numberOf` methods are in the `datasource`.  Everything else is in the `delegate`.

Comment: I have set the class to be both the datasource and the delegate.  that should be ok.  Right??  @interface DBEPatientVC () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

Comment: @turboc what you pasted into comment above shows that you've declared that your vc conforms to the protocol, but that's not all that's needed.  You must also set the datasource and delegate properties of the picker instance to your vc instance.  You can do this in code (like in view did load or in IB)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the pickerView.dataSource = ... to your controller;

Comment: Close, it was the delegate that had to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Igor's answer I got on the correct track.  I had to set the delegate to self in ViewDidLoad.

I already had a outlet named doctorPV for the picker view in the class and because the components and rows methods were getting called correctly, I thought the delegate was inferred by including the pickerviewdelegate protocol.  I guess it wasn't.

I added self.doctorPV.delegate=self to my viewDidLoad and everything works like magic.

Thanks Igor.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      your picker view controller.delegate=self;
    your picker view controller.dataSource=self;
}
```